# Multi-container deployment to azure app service through GitHub actions

Tags: azure-web-app-service, github-actions, azure-appservice, azure-deployment, azure-webapps

I have recently started with GitHub actions and I am stuck at seemingly trivial thing. I will appreciate your help with my question.

I am trying to deploy multiple images on Azure App Service through Github action. For sake of simplicity, I am only adding deployment job below.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'newapp'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_7c28e46039c5460897fa180b852b807d }}
        images: 'example.azurecr.io/app_main:0.0.10-amd64'
```

The above-mentioned code tries to deploy only one image to the azure app service and it runs successfully but when I am going for multi-container deployment and adding one more image to `images` parameter, it fails. Please check the code below and the error it runs into.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'newapp'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_7c28e46039c5460897fa180b852b807d }}
        images: |
            example.azurecr.io/app_main:0.0.1-amd64
            example.azurecr.io/helppage:0.0.0v1-amd64
```

This code results into following error-

```
Error: ERR_INVALID_CHAR
Error: Failed to deploy image to Web app Container.
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["linuxfxversion"]
```

The azure github documents says that we can add multiple images by adding multi-line separator - https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/blob/20cc095afa610e38d81c8cc19504cb6d9759fe2e/action.yml#L20

Am I not adding the separator correctly here? I have checked all over the internet on how to deploy multi-container application to App Service through github action but I didn't find any help. I will appreciate it if someone can guide me here.

Comment: I don't think your issue is with your workflow, but might be a bug in the action itself. The error message you are getting back indicates the deploy is sending an invalid character for an HTTP header. I would suggest opening an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/issues
I think the repository owners could help you track the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tj-cappelletti for the comment.

> ```yaml
> Error: ERR_INVALID_CHAR Error: Failed to deploy image to Web app Container. Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["linuxfxversion"]
> ```

As mentioned in the error there might be issue with Runtime Version Configuration.

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux&tabs=debian#syntax-limitations) and [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy#sample-workflow-to-build-and-deploy-a-nodejs-web-app-to-azure-using-publish-profile), we need to include the version on the top of the file.

> "version x.x" always needs to be the first YAML statement in the file

```cs
version:  'x.x'
```

From [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-container-show) I have used the Azure CLI command to check the Runtime Stack version.

```cs
az webapp config container show --name YourWebAppName --resource-group YourResourceGroupName
```

[image]

> The azure github documents says that we can add multiple images by adding multi-line separator

Yes,even the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-container-github-action?tabs=publish-profile#deploy-to-an-app-service-container) says the same.

Make sure there is no extra space or indent between the images.